# My site in laravel only shows "IP"

Tags: laravel

I just installed it in **cpanel** and I have a problem with my application in **Laravel**, when I want to access my application, it only shows me my hostname IP.

And he is not able to show me the content I have in: `./Public`

Show img:

[image: Imagen problems]

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I think it is a configuration problem, the application already worked correctly in my previous hosting, but after migrating it and configuring the database I am getting that error.